# Cannot overwrite variable because it is readonly

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to learn Powershell. I have the following script:

```
$cmd = {
  param($pid)
  Write-Host $pid
}

$processes = Get-Process -Name notepad
foreach ($process in $processes) 
{ 
    $pid = $process.ID
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $pid
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot overwrite variable PID because it is read-only or constant. At
>   line:7 char:1
>   + $pid = 1
>   + ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (PID:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable   Cannot overwrite variable PID because it is read-only or constant. At line:11 char:1
>   + $pid = $process.ID
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (PID:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable   Start-Job : Cannot overwrite variable pid because it is read-only or constant. At line:12
>   char:5
>   +     Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $pid

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$PID` is a [reserved, automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that contains the process id of your session.  You cannot set it.

See:

```
Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables
```

for a complete list and description of the automatic variables.

Edit:

To output the process ID's of all the Notepad processes:

```
 Get-Process -Name notepad |
   Select -ExpandProperty ID
```

Comment: Thanks, If I change it to different name, I get following result. I only want the process id. How can I do that?
 Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
2      Job2            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
4      Job4            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...

Comment: You need to explain what it is your trying to accomplish in the question a little better.

Comment: Just trying to print process id of all running notepad instances while using a function

Comment: hmm, I am not getting PID but that's a different question. I will post it.

Comment: here is the question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308385/how-to-get-process-id-of-a-running-process-as-shown-in-task-manager