# how to get process id of a running process as shown in task manager

Tags: windows, powershell, taskmanager

I am learning powershell and trying to see how can variables and functions could be used. I want to print out PID for all running notepad instances, basically what is shown in PID column under Details tab in Task manager. I have written following code

```
$cmd = {
  param($abc)
  Write-Host $abc
}

$processes = Get-Process -Name notepad | Select -ExpandProperty ID 
foreach ($process in $processes) 
{ 
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $process
}
```

I am getting following result.

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
50     Job50           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
52     Job52           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

Two issues here.
1. I only want PID, it has whole lot.
2. I expect that Id in above output is the PID but what is shown in task manager is very differnt.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PID vs ID

You are getting the PID's that you expect in `$processes` just fine. The issue here is that you are seeing the output from `Start-Job` and confusing its *Job* ID with your PID output.

You have 2 notepad.exe's running in your example so PowerShell, as requested, runs 2 jobs. The ID `50` and `52` are just the id assigned to the jobs. To get the output you are looking for you first need to capture it.

If at the end of your script you put `Get-Job | Receive-Job` you would have seen the PID's you were expecting. For more reading on jobs and job output you can find a great article on [TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx)

## However

Why are you using `Start-Job`? Is this part a greater script? You should just be able to use [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) as pass it the scriptblock `$cmd`.

```powershell
$cmd = {
  param($abc)
  Write-Host $abc
}

$processes = Get-Process -Name notepad | Select -ExpandProperty ID 
foreach ($process in $processes){ 
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $process
}
```

**Warning**

While this is not an issue in the PowerShell 5.0 you are using `Write-Host` for output in you example. If you need to use that output in another function you should consider calling `Write-Output` instead.

Comment: I changed my answer tnx

Comment: I will prefer a solution with Start-Job as I am planning to add some long running jobs within the $cmd. Can you update your answer as how to do it using Jobs

Comment: @pauldeter No issues with that and that is covered in my answer with `Get-Job | Receive-Job`. There are other ways to deal with Job output which is your next research assignment :).

Comment: @Matt your answer is using Invoke-Command. Can you update it using Start-Job. I am not sure how to use Get-Job here.

Comment: @pauldeter It is the line above "However" you can just put that as the last line. My answer was designed to cover your need __and__ provide an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

select just pid for notepad process :

```
 Get-Process -Name chrome | select Id | Format-List
```

for get stamps from your job run it just

```
Get-Job | select ID | Format-List
```

output

```
Id : 2
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. There is no correlation between a job id and process id.

Comment: @Matt when i select process identifier from task manager show that and i see pid not difference with Id result from ` Get-Process -Name chrome | select Id | Format-List` is not correct ?

Comment: Please see my answer. I think I know what the confusion was.